# Change performance & mouse settings via powershell (Show windows contents while dragging)

Tags: windows-10, powershell, virtual-machine, automation

I have a Powershell script that lets me workaround most of the annoyances with my VDI/Virtual Machine, which resets every morning - it opens all the apps I need, the directories, tools, etc... but there are a couple of other things I want to do to make it a bit quicker.

I was looking for a way to tweak the performance option for **"Show window contents while dragging" by setting it to true/checked**, and I wanted to change the mouse settings so the scheme is set to **"Windows Black (large)"**, and the **scroll wheel to scrolling 1 line at a time**.

I've had little luck finding how to set this specifically, whether it's editing a registry line, or, assuming I might not be able to do that without requiring admin permission, I can set it with other cmdlets.

Comment: Did you already tried the solutions in this  [article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/73d72328-38ed-4abe-a65d-83aaad0f9047/adjust-for-best-performance?forum=winserverpowershell)?

Comment: @CentrixDE no, because I want to change **one specific setting** for performance, and I was unable to find any information on the registry entry pertaining to it, and as I do not have admin rights, I am unable to open regedit to take a look ant see if such a registry entry already exists that I can tweak.  As for the mouse, same thing.  If there are cmdlets, I'm not aware of them.  If there are registry entries, I'm not aware of them, either...

Comment: So, as normally happens, a day of searching with no results, but after I ask a question on here, I find at least part of the solution.  [This article literally talks about changing the cursor with PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-change-the-mouse-pointer-scheme/) so I answered that part of my question... but as for specifically changing the one performance option... so far nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the "Show windows contents while dragging" with the following Regkey:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop
```

with the string value of `DragFullWindows`

0 = Show window outline while dragging

1 = Show window contents while dragging

You only need administrator privileges to write to locations that are shared on your computer. So therefore you only have the privileges to write to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`